# how to reduce app size after monetize (android)

Tags: android, apk

i created an app that was 64 KB in APK and 200 KB after installation but after when i monetized my app using [mMedia](http://mmedia.com/) library and google-play-services_lib my app size increaset to 1.25 mb in APK and after install its 2.79 mb.

i have seen many apps in small size like 300 kb  with ads (monetized) included then why my app size increased that much

so how can i reduce app size after monetizing my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding of google-play-services_lib project increase the size of apk.

> Remove unused/unnecessary resource from res folder (drawable-XXX, values-XXX).

many resource in google-play-services_lib\res folder is no use for you, you can remove it. such as values-af, values-am, .... what you need to keep is color, drawable, drawable-hdpi and values folder.

Clean and build the apk, you can see the reduction in the size of apk.